# Symfony2: Get HTML from another file in controller

Tags: php, html, symfony

In my Symfony2 project, I would like to get the HTML of a file and put it in a variable in my controller.

I have a controller function like this:

```
public function myControllerAction()
{
   $htmlOtherFile = '';

   return $this->render('@MyBundle/myTargetFile.html.twig', ['htmlOtherFile' => $htmlOtherFile]);
}
```

The html file I would like to import is in my views folder: `htmlOtherFile.html.twig`

How can I get the `HTML` of this file into my `$htmlOtherFile` variable? I have already tried with `file_get_contents`, but without success.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

all you need to do is call `renderView` from your controller on the template and put the contents in a variable.

```
$html = $this->renderView('/path/myTargetFile.html.twig', [/*options in here*/]);
```

Be sure to call `renderView` and not `render` on its own as that will return a `Response` instance, and not any HTML.

Alternatively, you can call:

```
$this->render('/path/myTargetFile.html.twig', [/*options in here*/])->getContent();
```

to return the html from the response.

Comment: Why don't you edit an Ilya's answer? He answered with that solution first.

Comment: because there was more to add, and I dont write peoples answers for them.

Answer (score 2):

If it is twig file - you could try this:

```
$this->renderView('/path/to/template.html.twig', []);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can call a controller directly from you twig file if you want.

Use the syntax `{{ render(controller('MyBundle:functionName')) }}`